# EC2 instances are not being attached to ECS Clusters Automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have been trying to run a demo hello world container on ECS and created an ECS cluster from the AWS console with the following config.

[image]

However, when I'm trying to run a task to this container, It's saying, "You don't have any EC2 instances registered to your cluster. Your tasks won't be able to be run.".

[image]

I tried to google the problem, but AWS recently changed their UI, and almost everything I found on the internet is outdated and doesn't match the current flow. Also, I am considerably new to this arena and having a difficult time understanding a lot of things.

Can anyone give me a hand resolving this matter?

Comment: You've selected a list of both public and private subnets for some reason. That is definitely the wrong thing to do there. You need to decide if you want your instances to be in public or private subnets and stick with that. As for why you have no registered instances, you need to go look in the EC2 console to see if instances have been successfully created. And look at the AutoScaling group in the EC2 console to see if it is restarting servers for any reason.

Comment: It was a mistake. I tried with public subnets only and still got the same result. The EC2 instance did create but I noticed that there were no public IP assigned to those instances.

In the old UI of creating a cluster, there was an option ```Auto assign public IP```, which allows you to assign public IP upon creation. I have noticed that this option is not available in the new UI; hence no public IP was assigned to those instances, and they were not available under the cluster. 

Didn't find any solution but things are working with old UI.

Comment: Yeah, I think I didn't assign public IP to the EC2 instances during creation. Can't remember the exact reason though.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue,

msg="Unable to register as a container instance with ECS: RequestError: send request failed\ncaused by: Post "https://ecs.us-west-2.amaz.com/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)" module=client.go

Problem was due to the security group not allowing https.

steps to fix.

1. create a new security group allowing https.
2. go to instance and add newly created security group.
   test
3. if works, you can go to launch template add new security group
4. set the default to new version
5. in Auto Scaling group set the version of lauch template to the latest version.